# SQL MINUS/EXCEPT command analog for columns only while INSERTion

Tags: sql, postgresql

Does MINUS/EXCEPT command or code workaround analog exist for columns only? Since MINUS/EXCEPT command fine for rows, how about for columns?

Mask-table (physically exist):

```
id       col1 col2 col3 col4 ... colN comment
doesn't   A    B    C    D   ...  Z   --alphabet correct sequence
matter
```

Columns Data Type of col[i] equals to each other.

Incoming select-stream (not a physical table, but represented as table as a result of other complex joined-selection from other tables):

```
 col1 col2 col3 col4 ... colN comment
  A    B    C    D   ...  Z   --alphabet correct seq
  A    C    B    D   ...  Z   --incorrect
  E    B    C    M   ...  Z   --incorrect
... 
  Z    Y    X    W   ...  A   --full inverse icorrect
```

Expected output to physical table after processing mask-table to select-stream as insert result:

```
id      col1  col2  col3  col4 ... colN
(auto-
gnrtd)
       (null)(null)(null)(null)...(null)
       (null)  C     B   (null)...(null)
         E   (null)(null)  M   ...(null)
...
         Z     Y     X     W   ...  A
```

**Please note: alphabet is given just as an example. Not the issue-case here. SQL-Logic/command required. Analog of MINUS/EXCEPT, but for columns (DISTINCT? How, if incoming select-stream is a result of other complex joined-select)**

What will be the SQL-code for this task? Please, advise.

Comment: I don't understand why `A` is replaced with `NULL` in the second line. Anyway, this looks like a bunch of `CASE` expressions would do the trick.

Comment: Because col1 == A in stream matches col1 == A in mask. Full MINUS gives (null)

Comment: Stream-row MINUS mask-table-row but for columns only. Please note: it has to be done while inserting it to expected-result table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to do it without CASE statements:

**Setup**

```
CREATE TABLE mask (
  col1 TEXT,
  col2 TEXT,
  col3 TEXT,
  col4 TEXT,
  col5 TEXT
);

INSERT INTO mask SELECT 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E';

CREATE TABLE your_stream (
  col1 TEXT,
  col2 TEXT,
  col3 TEXT,
  col4 TEXT,
  col5 TEXT
);

INSERT INTO your_stream
VALUES
('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'),
('A', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'E'),
('E', 'B', 'C', 'M', 'E');
```

---

**Query**

```
SELECT
  NULLIF(s.col1, m.col1) AS col1,
  NULLIF(s.col2, m.col2) AS col2,
  NULLIF(s.col3, m.col3) AS col3,
  NULLIF(s.col4, m.col4) AS col4,
  NULLIF(s.col5, m.col5) AS col5
FROM your_stream s
CROSS JOIN mask m;
```

---

**Result**

```
| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 |
| ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- |
| null | null | null | null | null |
| null | C    | B    | null | null |
| E    | null | null | M    | null |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ffxToqcaoD2MV25wDpxjpb/0)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what the connection to a set operation like `EXCEPT` would be.

Anyway, this is how you could proceed:

```
INSERT INTO destination (col1, col2, col3, ...)
SELECT CASE WHEN incoming_col1 <> mask.col1
            THEN incoming_col1
       END,
       CASE WHEN incoming_col2 <> mask.col2
            THEN incoming_col2
       END,
       ...
FROM mask;
```

Comment: `EXCEPT` - for rows

`?` - for columns, while columns in rows being inserted to destination-table. `DISTINCT`?

Comment: Huh? What are you trying to tell me?

Comment: Nothing new, but **bold text** in task description. But thank you anyway